# Skeletal animation using directx 11

Tags: c++, directx11

I tried to find tutorials about skeletal animation or books that talk about subject to implement it, but I couldn't find any tutorials except talking md5 animated files. I would like tutorials that talk about that subject.

Comment: As far as I know, DX SDK has a sample on skeletal animation, though I'm not sure if it has been ported to d3d11, but for d3d9 there is one named "SkinnedMesh".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skeletal animaion is not specific to DirectX or a single file format. There are many articles on skeletal animation in general to help you with understanding how it works.

I would recommend working with MD5 while learning as it is a text based format, which should make it easier to play with values. (More info on the format: http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md5-specs-en.html)
or the Blitz3D model format (http://www.blitzbasic.com/sdkspecs/sdkspecs/b3dfile_specs.txt).

I would first worry about making sure whatever format you choose, that you can load it first. Then, the format you use shouldn't matter and you should be able to just deal with the math (Which any tutorial should be able to teach).

Note: do keep in mind that joint animation has slightly altered math from bone animation